# join a set of names on a un-formatted column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure how to go about this, but basically I have a set of names

`'USDE', 'USTX', 'USPA', 'SEMA' ... 'SEPO'`

This set of names does not exist in a specific table but its set of names given to me

and I need to do a join on these on a table which has the same names, but they may have additional text either leading or trailing or both.

`'S1\USDE', 'S1\USTX\admin', 'USPA\localadmon'`

So how can I find every user with the name in the first list that exist in the second list?

I'm running SQL Server 2008

Comment: And how do you access you DB? If you need to use straight SQL, it might be difficult. However if you would use something like C#, ASPX, etc.. you could easily program it i think. Bottom line, you need to explain better what it is you need to do, this is not enough.

Comment: Why not simply import the list into a table, and then build a query to do the lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `JOIN` between tables using `LIKE`, here is a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE #nameSet (namePart varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE #data (name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO #nameSet VALUES('USDE');
INSERT INTO #nameSet VALUES('USTX');
INSERT INTO #nameSet VALUES('USPA');
INSERT INTO #nameSet VALUES('SEMA');
INSERT INTO #nameSet VALUES('SEPO');

INSERT INTO #data VALUES('S1\USDE');
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('S1\USTX\admin');
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('USPA\localadmon');
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('S1\XXXX\admin');

SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    #data AS s
    INNER JOIN #nameSet AS n ON s.name LIKE '%' + n.namePart + '%';
```